# Geolocation in Safari 5

Tags: html, safari, geolocation

I have a application which reports my location using HTML5 geolocation. The application works correct on Firefox and Chrome, but on Safari 5, it says that Safari does not support Geolocation.

From what I read, Safari 5 does support Geolocation. What am I missing?

Thanks for your time.

Sunil

Comment: So this wasn't solved in 6 years almost?

Comment: Faced the same issue, turned out I have to enable location services in Mac's System Preferences.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like Safari geolocation only works when connected with wifi. When connected with a wired connection Safari calls the error callback from the geolocation functions.

To test this, try this in the web console:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  function(){console.log("success")},
  function(){console.log("error")}
);
```

With Safari/wifi this returns 'success' after a second or two, but on a wired connection it returns 'error' immediately.

( using Safari 5.1 - 8.x / Mac OSX 10.7 - 10.10 )

Comment: Thanks Andy. I tried it over Wi fi and the geolocation worked well on Safari.

Comment: There may be something more going on here. Yesterday this was the case, but today I am getting 'success' on my wired connection. All I can remember changing is installing the developer tools.

Comment: There is definitely something going on here. Using Safari 5.1 (also happened with previous version), sometimes Geolocation works, sometimes not at all. Usually get a timeout error. With absolutely no changes to my system. But I have no idea what the problem might be. All other browsers seem to work perfectly.

Comment: Does anyone else notice @andyvanee 's problem with developer tools?

Answer (score 3):

Although [nominally](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/html5.html) geolocation support in Safari 5 is available on both Mac and Windows, I'm hearing of more issues on the Windows side.

For example, see this similar [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686630/geolocation-not-workin-on-safari-5-x-on-windows-7-xp). In that case, though, `navigator.geolocation` was available, it just never received a successful callback. When you say that "it says that Safari does not support Geolocation", who is saying that to you? Are you getting an error callback, is `navigator.geolocation` null, or have you just read this elsewhere (and if so, where?)?

Comment: It may be that the user has disabled geolocation features.

Comment: Yes, that is one possibility, in which case I believe that `navigator.geolocation` should be null.

Comment: i have a javascript alert setup for cases when geolocation is not available. Chrome and Firefox do not trigger this alert. Only Safari 5 does.

Comment: @npdoty i checked my code again and I see that Safari does return null or undefined as return value. My application captures this state and alerts the user that the browser does not support geoLocation.

Comment: @Sunil That might suggest that Location services are disabled: can you check in your Safari settings? (On a Mac, Safari > Preferences > Security > Location services; should be similar on Windows.) And Firefox and Chrome are returning correct locations on the same machine?

Comment: Yes Chrome and Firefox work without any problem on the same machine. I checked the preferences on Safari and it is enabled to share locations.Thanks

Comment: At that point I have no other suggestion than to file a bug against Safari: http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/. If Location Services enabled, navigator.geolocation should be defined, if not, it's a bug. Give them details on your operating system and configuration, of course, as we're obviously not all seeing this behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I have filed a bug report to Apple. Hoping they fix it soon.

Comment: @SunilShenoy did they fix it? Obviously not - Safari and iOS not working for me..

Answer (score 3):

How do you fetch Google Maps API script ? Is sensor param set to true or false ?
I had Safari Geolocation not working (under Windows) until I changed "sensor=false" to "sensor=true" like the example below:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And it works perfectly in every browser : IE9, Chrome, FF10+, Safari (Win).

**Noticed another strange thing** - it works only with WiFi in Safari - if you wired-connected, it won't work and would just stuck trying forever.

So, to fix Safari just add the following `{ maximumAge: 600000, timeout: 10000 }` to handle timeout :

```
// Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred)
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        handleGeolocationAcquired(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    }, function(error) {
        handleNoGeolocation();
    },
        { maximumAge: 600000, timeout: 10000 });

    // Try Google Gears Geolocation
} else if (google.gears) {
    var geo = google.gears.factory.create('beta.geolocation');
    geo.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        handleGeolocationAcquired(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    }, function () {
        handleNoGeolocation();
    });
}
//Cannot obtain Geo Location
else {
    handleNoGeolocation();
}
```

This way, in case you're in Safari (under Windows) and wired-connected (=> endless loop acquiring Geo location) : after 10 seconds, it will fallback to error handler. 
BTW - **maximumAge** param just sets location expiration.

Comment: Not working for me. I'm using async and defer to load the script (i need autosuggest and other apis also..) and Safari no-go ...

Answer (score 2):

hmmm, I'm a little stumped.  Safari 5 does support geolocation through HTML 5.  You might want to try to use an HTML 5 feature detection service like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com).  This will tell you what browsers support html5 and css3 standards.  I'm using Safari 5 and Modernizr shows that the geolocation API is supported.

Comment: Geolocation API is supported but it does not work on Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `getCurrentPosition(...)` without specified timeout makes Safari stuck there for minutes.

Comment: It does not work even with given timeout (safari only)