# How to get current position(city,state,zipcode) in safari browser ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have tried below code its work for chrom,firefox browser but not work on safari browser on desktop(wired connection) and also not work in windows phone(tested on nokia lumia 625.) but work on my ipad,iphone (through wifi) for safari browser.
Please give me a solution for this issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"> </script>
```

in my header call function on load page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    requestPosition();
});
```

write function in js file

```
function requestPosition() {

    if (typeof navigator.geolocation == "undefined") {

        alert("Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API");
        return;

    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode({
        "location": new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude)
    },
    function (results, status) {

      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            j = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < results[j].address_components.length; i++) {

              if (results[j].address_components[i].types[0] == "locality") {
                  //this is the object you are looking for

                 city = results[j].address_components[i];
             }

             if (results[j].address_components[i].types[0] == "administrative_area_level_1") {

                //this is the object you are looking for
                region = results[j].address_components[i];

            }

            if (results[j].address_components[i].types[0] == "country") {

                //this is the object you are looking for
                country = results[j].address_components[i];
            }
        }

            city=city.long_name;
            state=region.long_name;
            country=country.long_name;

            $("#_state").val(state);
            $("#_country").val(country);
            $("#_city").val(city);
        }
        else
                        alert("Unable to retrieve your address");
    });
},
   function (positionError) {
    alert("Error: " + positionError.message);
   },
   {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 10 * 1000 // 10 seconds
   }
}
```

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791442/geolocation-in-safari-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari geolocation only works when connected with wifi. When connected with a wired connection Safari calls the error callback from the geolocation functions.

Comment: What is the solution for safari browser on wired connection ? How to get the city,state,timezone of login user ?

Comment: Sorry till date i haven't found solution for wired connection !! if i find something i ll let u know.