# Geolocation not supported in Safari with wired connection?

Tags: javascript, safari, geolocation

I am trying out geolocation in Javascript, writing a very small web app on codepen. I mainly use Safari (10.1.2) on my macbook (10.12.6) and I couldn't get the following geolocation code working :

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  let longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  getRequest(latitude, longitude);
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error.code);
});
```

After some time I opened up Chrome and tested the same code, it worked. I started doing some research on Safari and geolocation and have seen some people mention wired connection being the culprit.

I tried with wifi and indeed, it works. I don't know why, and couldn't find an explanation anywhere, but Safari refuses to handle geolocation when connected via Ethernet.

I did the same test on Google Maps and geolocation works everytime. So I thought maybe my code is wrong but I have the same trouble with code from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp). I'm guessing Google uses another method.

How can I make it work on Safari with a wired connection ? I'm surprised to [find posts from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791442/geolocation-in-safari-5) and to be facing the same problem 7 years later with all software up to date. Is there a universally compatible method I'm missing ? I'm wondering how services depending on geolocation handle this problem.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does it work on Safari w/ a wireless connection?

Comment: He says, "I tried with wifi and indeed, it works."

Comment: Well it doesn't seem to work in the code editor here, but it works on Codepen and the code from W3Schools is very similar. It doesn't ask permission to get location, maybe something with the fact that the code is not run at page load or something.