# W3C geolocation API not working on Safari 5

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, w3c

W3C geolocation API doesn't seem to work in safari 5.
I tried this page and it sort of tells me that Geolocation is unsuccessful.

The code:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation.html

can somebody explain me why this is so?

Comment: the link provided worked for me. I'm using Safari 5.0.4 on Mac OSX 10.6.6 and are in Germany at the moment. This kind of information might help people to figure out what is wrong in your case. Also could take a look at safari's developer tools.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, using Safari 5.0.4 on Windows.  The browser asks if I can share my location, I say Allow and the web page can't get my location.  Works in other browsers, just not Safari.

Answer (score 11):

Looks like geolocation in safari only works when you're connected to wifi (not wired):
[Geolocation in Safari 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791442/geolocation-in-safari-5/6852029#6852029)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Safari 5.0.5 on Mac Snow Leopard and clicking after on your link I was getting

```
Error: The Geolocation service failed
```

Try enabling the location services in Safari.

Go to Preferences->Security and check "Allow websites to ask for location information". Also, make sure System Preferences->Security does not have "Disable Location Services" checked.

Now all works as expected and I'm getting

```
Location found using W3C standard
```

Comment: You are using Mac Snow Leopard. Does it work on Windows 7 though? Please don't take this as a complaint about your answer, as the original question didn't specify Windows versus Mac.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you're working on a Mac and none of the other answers helped, check that the `Safari` application is permitted to determine your location:

System Preferences --> Security and Privacy --> Privacy --> Location Services --> Check the Safari checkbox.

Refresh the [page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation?csw=1), if prompted, allow Safari to obtain your location and now you should be able to see your location on the map.

The above was reproduced on OS X El Capitan.