# Geolocation/Maps API Directions not displaying on map

Tags: google-maps, safari, geolocation

In Safari I have an issue with the Google Maps API directions service. I use HTML5 Geolocation  to display directions to a location on page load.

Here is a page that uses this.
http://northwestmarkets.com/all-stores/arlington-food-pavilion

What about Safari could cause this error. I works in IE, Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Open System Preferences / Security and select the General tab.

Click the gold padlock icon bottom left in the pane to make any necessary changes. You will be prompted for your admin password.

If necessary, make sure: Disable Location Services is not selected. Click: Reset Warnings.

support: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4239

also checkout this [W3C geolocation API not working on Safari 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256123/w3c-geolocation-api-not-working-on-safari-5), looks like in safari 5 geolocation only works with wifi

Comment: Thank you, It looks like there is nothing I can do on the developer end.