# Why is geolocate failing in safari desktop?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

I trying to use geolocation and it's working for all my browsers except for safari.

Here is the script that I'm running.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (location) {
        console.log('success');
    }, function () {
        console.log('error');
    });
} else {
    console.log('denied');
}
```

[I've created a fiddle for this as well](http://jsfiddle.net/ddJUq/)

I'm running safari 5.1.7 on windows 7 pro.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256123/w3c-geolocation-api-not-working-on-safari-5

Comment: Unfortunately no, it still fails over wifi.

Comment: I also just verified that it works on Safari on OSX.

Comment: Define "failing". What happens? Does the error message fire? Does the denied message fire? (It is worth noting that Apple no longer support Safari for Windows, so I'd expect a shrinking user base and unpatched security holes for it so I'd give it as much support as I give to IE6/7)

Comment: I get prompted for my location, then when I click "allow" the error message gets logged.  This happens on wifi as well.  It works with no problem in OSX

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer. Just want to add a little "me too" with some little fragments.

This is very peculiar. I've had no trouble with this feature for years, wired, wifi, whatever.

Now it has just started failing (Mac Snow Leopard, Safari 5.1.10). Link to fiddle fails, google's example fails, my own code which has been working fine for years also fails. Sometimes it's error code 2, sometimes just a timeout. (I am using timeout of 60000 - one minute).

Works fine on other browsers. Also no problem with iOS Safari connected to the exact same wireless network.

Comment: We aren't supposed to add a +1 but this really is affecting me too and it's inexplicable. Same type of issue, always code 2, only safari, every website that uses geolocation in fact, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I wish I had good news, but no. And I have not been using geolocation for a while, so not sure about the status of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

No you code is right

actually all the browser get the geolocation but only safari browser not getting geolocation if you are using wired connection but if you are using wifi then it will work.

I don't know why this problem occur only in safari browser.I have same problem and I am try for alternate way to get geolocation if any one find alternate way then please post on stack overflow.