# Trouble testing/debugging web geolocation app on OS X in Safari. Is there a Safari setting for geolocation development?

Tags: html, safari, geolocation, osx-mountain-lion

I'm developing a javascript web application on OS X.  I have found that geolocation watchpoints don't trigger in Safari 6.0 ond OS X 10.8 so I can't test my apps functionality.  They do trigger in Chrome and Firefox.  What I'm wondering is there some Safari setting (or extension) that will make watchpoints work?

This is mostly just annoying as I'd like to test my app on my laptop for all major browsers.  After pushing changes to my server, I can test mobile safari well enough.

Specifically, Here is my code:

#### Relevant Code

```
var geoOptions = {
    timeout: 5000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    maximumAge: 0
};

$(document).on("pageshow", '#overviewStory', function() {
    if (!watchPointId)
    {
        mhLog.log(mhLog.LEVEL.DEBUG, "Start Watch");
        watchPointId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(locationEventHandler,      displayError, geoOptions);
    }
});
```

#### Summary

So, to reiterate, on OS 10.8 in Safari 6.0, the "locationEventHandler" function is never called.  Is there a Safari setting to change this? (Make geolocation work?)

#### Related

The answer to this may also answer this: [question] ([Geolocation not workin on Safari 5.x on Windows 7/XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686630/geolocation-not-workin-on-safari-5-x-on-windows-7-xp))