# html5 geolocation not working on safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, windows, safari, geolocation

working on html5 geolocation.

tried on mozilla, chrome, IE. working fine on them but not working for safari. tested on safari(8.0.5) on mac,  safari(5.1) on windows

simply hitting the url

```
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp
```

OR

```
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

it gives popup Allow/Disallow but does nothing after allowing it.
And i have tested for safari on Mac connected with wi-fi But not for laptop on wi-fi and LAN too.

Comment: If possible could your consider troubleshooting this by taking a machine you’re testing in on trying it over wifi from another network somewhere else? For example, trying it from a public wifi hotspot if you can.

Comment: Unfortunately when Safari does this it seems there may be no useful way to programmatically get information back about the reason for the failure (for example, if it’s the case that it’s failing because the machine is using an ethernet connection, that detail is not exposed by Safari in any way you can get to). But in this case you should try other Web applications that use the Geolocation API (for example, demo apps in tutorial sites on the Web) and see if they are also failing in Safari in your environment (they almost certainly will be). In which case, there’s nothing you can do to fix it.

Comment: @sideshowbarker thanks for your suggestion :),  i have tested for safari on Mac connected with wi-fi  its working there, But not for laptop on wi-fi and LAN too.

Comment: OK, it seems then that you’re definitely running into known issue documented at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791442/geolocation-in-safari-5—which is that geolocation in Safari will not work from a machine with a wired/ethernet connection, and there is no fix or workaround for that problem.

Comment: @sideshowbarker is there problem for windows? i mean it is working on mac but not on windows connected with same wi-fi

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe Safari on Windows was end-of-lifed quite a while ago by Apple, right? And I’m not sure that it had very many users to begin with. So I think you should probably not even bother spending time testing Safari on Windows—unless you have some real intended users of your code who are running Safari on Windows for some reason. (Which I would doubt you actually do, right?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you connected with wi-fi or over cable network?

It seems safari has trouble when you aren't connected with wi-fi.

Source

[Geolocation not workin on Safari 5.x on Windows 7/XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686630/geolocation-not-workin-on-safari-5-x-on-windows-7-xp)

[Geolocation in Safari 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791442/geolocation-in-safari-5)

Comment: @ParanOa tried with both, but getting same trouble.

Comment: @Kamini are you certain you tested in Safari with wifi enabled? With your ethernet cable unplugged? Because the other StackOverlfow answers that are cited here indicate that other people have run into the exact same problem you reported, but only when they are used a “wired” (ethernet) connection (in which case it seems that Safari sometimes or always just returns an error rather than attempting to determine the location).

Comment: @ParanOa Hi it is working for--> safari on MAc with wi-fi But not for --> safari on Windows with wi-fi.

Comment: https://help.tunnelbear.com/customer/portal/articles/1543492-troubleshooting-geolocation-content-access-issues

Please check this website out. See if youre getting the sama data with mac and windows connected on the same wifi.

Comment: @Paran0a link https://bearsmyip.com/ shows the location on windows, but 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error this link not working. what might be the problem?

Comment: Could it be that only w3school is not working for you?
Can you try http://html5demos.com/geo also?

Comment: @Paran0a html5demos.com/geo site also not working giving message "loacation failed"

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you then. It unclear what kind of problem Safari has. People reported that sometimes it started working without much trouble. Sometimes they say that it starts working once you install developer tools. Try with this code in your web console as a final check navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  function(){console.log("success")},
  function(){console.log("error")}
);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91452/discussion-between-kamini-and-paran0a).

Comment: I confirm this, on Safari 11.1. Connected with ethernet cable, geolocation does not work, it does not give any kind of error, it just dies. Connected via wi-fi works

Answer (score 4):

Based on the example in the question, the following is a complete working snippet:

```html
<p id=demo>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
getLocation()
</script>
```

The actual example in the question is incomplete, so it would never do anything as-is by itself. So it’s hard to know what might have been working in Mozilla, Chrome, and IE without seeing the complete code.

If the above snippet still doesn’t work for you in your Safari, open Safari’s Web Inspector (for example, from the **Develop** menu or by right-clicking on the page and selecting **Inspect Element**), and go to the **Console** tab there and check to see what errors have been logged.

For now, as far as the code snippet, some basic points to note:

- the script must actually call the `getLocation()` function (not just define it)
- the document must actually have an `id=demo` element
- the script should be placed after the `id=demo` element (if you put the call to `getLocation()` in, for example, the `head` of the document, it’s not going to work, because it will run before the `id=demo` element exists in the DOM)

And never use w3schools.com for anything. It’s sloppy and highly unreliable and very poorly maintained. Instead use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). For example, MDN has a very good [Using geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) page, with [complete code for a good live example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation#Geolocation_Live_Example).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @sideshowbarker i have updated the code and also checked the MDN example on Safari on Mac and Windows but giving the message "Unable to retrieve your location".  please help.

Answer (score 2):

Well unfortunately Apple does not serve geolocation data over HTTP connections. You'll need HTTPS in order to access the client geolocation on Safari.

Comment: This answer is partially correct. See the answer above about LAN versus WiFi... I testted it over HTTPS and it definitely was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript geolocation was not asking the user to share location on iOS and Desktop Safari. Turners out that HTTPS and error handling are required for sites for Safari to share the location. Once I added the SSL certificate, it worked!